# Diff Util implementation in Recycler scrolling it to the top on every refresh

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using DiffUtil implementation to add new data to the RecyclerView on  scroll.

This is the code that is used to update the items when required.

```
final DiffUtilsCallback<Movie> diffUtilsCallback = new DiffUtilsCallback<>(this.movies, movies);
final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtilsCallback);

this.movies.clear();
this.movies.addAll(movies);
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
```

Every time new items are added, the RecyclerView is scrolled to the top item. How do I make sure that the scroll doesn't happen when new items are added.

I have overwritten the objects equals method so that it compares objects with the ID.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Movie)) return false;
    Movie movie = (Movie) obj;
    return this.id == movie.id;
}
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? Please post it as an answer if you have

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code it can be that your diffutil callback used to see how to compare the movies is comparing object wise instead of by an internal id you may have per film.

If you are comparing the objects directly which is the default implementation, and since you are clearing your array, this comparison will fail for all the new objects that you are adding. You need to change how you compare the elements so diffutil does not interpret all of them as changed.

Comment: I overwrote the default implementation to compare the objects with its ID. So it does compare the objects with its ID. I have updated the question with the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

My setData of the adapter was like this:

```
fun setData(movies: List<Movies>, shouldClear: Boolean = false) {
        val diffCallback = MovieDiffUtil(myDataSet, movies)
        val diffMovies = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        if (shouldClear) {
            this.myDataSet.clear()
        }
        this.myDataSet.addAll(movies)
        diffMovies.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

I have pagination and `movies` are just the new set of data that does not include the old data. So while DiffUtils check for the difference, everything is new. So instead of sending only the new data, send all the data(old data + new upcoming data) to `setData()`

Let me know if I am not clear.